# Word document info panel SOAP Query and other errors!

Tags: word, soap, dip

Really pulling my hair out to fix this problem in my app. I just cannot get the information document panel associated with a content type to show properly in Word.

I have:
- a Document library in my Sharepoint App
- a content type associated with it, the content type has 1 required Lookup Column which looks up values from another list within the app

What happens is:

1. When I click Files --> New --> Select Content Type, then the Word client app launches as expected, but my Document Info Panel is not shown.
2. When I save the file back to SP I get the message bar that the file is checked out (since required info is missing):
   [image]
3. When I then click Check In I get the following error message:
   [image]
4. When I then close the file without checking in, reopen the file in Word client then I get the following message bar:
   [image]
5. When I then click the Edit Properties button to fill out the required information I get a weird SOAP query error, saying that "Value does not fall within the expected range":
   [image]
6. When I click OK the Doc Info Panel finally shows, but no values are given in the Lookup Column "Rol":
   [image]

I am really clueless what to do here... No clue where the SOAP error is coming from, neither do I know where I can check what goed wrong here. Rebuilt the library several times already and I just keep on running into this error no matter what I try...

Also I don't have any idea where the list ID from the SOAP call error message comes from, can't find that number anywhere in my entire solution???

All help will be highly appreciated!!!

Edit: if I select the checked out document in the Libarary and the go to Files --> Change Properties the Document Info Panel DOES show the Loojkup Column correctly!!!!

Edit2: Have the panel launching now in Word straight away, but the Lookup Field now gives the SOAP error directly and shows the Lookup Field in the DIP, but the dropdown has no values. Since it does work correctly when uploading a document within the doc library I think it has something to do with Word not finding the Lookup list. Lookup Field is defined as follows:

```
<Field ID="{a2f0999e-d683-41a7-a3c1-aa8abcca5a04}" 
Name="scRol" 
DisplayName="Rol" 
Type="Lookup" 
Required="false" 
List="Lists/lstRollen" 
ShowField="scRolnaam" 
UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="FALSE" 
Group="Custom Site Columns">
</Field>
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I share you pain as I am having similar issues. I recreated the Document Information Panel

Content Type -> settings -> Document Info Panel ..  Which opens up the InfoPath designer

I had to upgrade the data connection as I got a warning about an older version .

Keep the _List but you can modify its values so that it brings inc your lookup list IF field (Title) .. Publish back to SharePoint and otpionally save locallly.

...No soap errors but my damn lookup values are just check boxes with a number next to them ahhhhhhhhhh

Comment: At least you got somewhat further, i'll try this as well tomorrow